# Collection was modified; enumeration may not execute error when removing a ListItem from a LIstBox

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have two ListBoxes, lstAvailableColors and lstSelectedColors.  Between each listbox are two buttons, Add and Remove.  When a color or colors is selected in lstAvailableColors and the Add button is clicked, I want to remove them from lstAvailableColors and display them in lstSelectedColors.  Also, if colors are selected in lstSelectedColors and the Remove button is clicked, I want to remove the colors from lstSelectedColors and add them back to lstAvailableColors.  When I do this, I get the following error when it removes the item:

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Here is the code for the Add Button and the Remove Button:

Add:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in lstAvailableColors.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(item);
            lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Remove:

```
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in lstSelectedColors.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            lstAvailableColors.Items.Add(item);
            lstSelectedColors.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do I loop through items in a list box and then remove that item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380451/how-do-i-do-i-loop-through-items-in-a-list-box-and-then-remove-that-item)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not possible to modify a collection while you're enumerating it in .Net.  You need to separate out your enumeration and remove code into different blocks.  Here is a quick sample on how to do that in without LINQ

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem item in lstAvailableColors.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selected.Add(item);
            lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    foreach (ListItem item in selected)
    {
        lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

And here's a more concise version using LINQ

```
var selected = lstAvailableColors.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
selected.ForEach( x => { lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(x); });
selected.ForEach( x => { lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(x);});
```

**EDIT**

The LINQ version works in two parts.  The first part is the first line which finds the currently selected items and stores the value in a `List<ListItem>`.  It's very important that the line contain the .ToList() call because that forces the query to execute immediately vs. being delayed executed.

The next two lines iterate through each value which is selected and remove or add it to the appropriate list.  Because the selected list is already stored we are no longer enumerating the collection when we modify it.

Comment: Can you explain the LINQ version?

Comment: "with LINQ" should be "without LINQ" in the first example ;)

Comment: Thank you for your solution but i need to ask if this is possible with one of the listboxes being able to select more than one value.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot modify an collection while you are using an Enumerator for this collection, what the for each statement does.

You have to loop over the data with a normal for loop and then you can modify the collection, but you must be careful to correctly update the current index if you insert or remove elements. If you just add or remove elements and don't insert some, iterating from the last element to the first will do.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (Int32 i = lstAvailableColors.Items.Count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ListItem item = lstAvailableColors.Items[i];

        if (item.Selected)
        {
            lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(item);
            lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify a collection you are iterating on.  In general, a good solution for this type of problem is to create an empty collection, and in your iterator, copy over all of the elements you do NOT want to remove; after the iteration is complete, replace the original collection with your new collection.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer mentioned, you can't remove items until you've completed the iteration.  So perhaps something like this will be cleanest for you:

```
var itemsToRemove =
lstAvailableColors.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.IsSelected).ToArray();

foreach(ListItem item in itemsToRemove) lstAvailableColors.Remove(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection while you're iterating over it.  Either iterate over a copy or use for, iterate in reverse and remove as you go down.

Comment: for (int i=lstSelectedColors.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) { if ( lstSelectedColors.Items[i].Selected] ) { lstSelectedColors.Items.Remove(lstSelectedColors.Items[i]); } }

Comment: You contradict yourself; you say you cannot modify a collection while you are iterating over it (no direction specified), but you immediately say that the solution is to iterate in reverse.  It's just generally a bad idea to modify a collection you're iterating over, forward or reverse.

Comment: I was using iterate too loosely.  Foreach enumerates over a collection.  You can't modify it while enumerating over the collection.  But you can modify it by using a for loop and starting at the end of the collection.

Comment: I contend that it is still a bad idea to modify a collection while iterating over it (even using a for loop).  It may work, but it's generally bad form.

Comment: agreed, though I'm curious - why do you say it's bad form?  What's bad about it?

Comment: because even if you iterate in reverse, there's nothing to stop you from modifying items in the enumeration BEFORE the one you are currently on, and then you're hosed.  You can iterate forward and [carefully] modify items you haven't gotten to yet as well, but its just generally way too easy to screw this up, so it better not to dio it at all, as a matter of good practice

Answer (score 0):

Example on how to remove the selected Items. Here only the selected indices are taken and removed.

```
   public void RemoveSelectedItems(ListBox listbox)
   {
       List<ListItem> items = GetSelectedItems(listbox);
       foreach (var listItem in items)
       {
           listbox.Items.Remove(listItem);
       }
   }

  public List<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(ListBox listbox)
  {
     int[] selectedIndices = listbox.GetSelectedIndices();
     return selectedIndices.Select(index => listbox.Items[index]).ToList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while(listBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1)
    {
           listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you;

### To Remove:

```
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstAvailableColors.Items.Count; i++)
        { 
            if(lstAvailableColors.Items[i].Selected)
                lstAvailableColors.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that you can't modify the collection you itterate thru. You could solve this by using a single linq:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstAvailableColors.Items.RemoveAll(ac => ac.Selected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic function to remove mulitple items form ObservableCollection ( I know that many are scared of Exceptions, but Exception is nothing but a dev tool)

```
    public static void OCRemoveMultiple<T>(ref ObservableCollection<T> inputList, IList<T> toRemoveItems)
    {
        REITERATE:
        {
            try
            {
                while( inputList.Intersect<T>(toRemoveItems).Any())
                {
                    var intersectionList = inputList.Intersect<T>(toRemoveItems);
                    foreach (var item in intersectionList)
                    {
                        inputList.Remove(item);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                goto REITERATE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a test case (an example) how you can use it:

```
        ObservableCollection<object> targetList = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        targetList.Add("T1");
        targetList.Add("T2");
        targetList.Add("B3");
        targetList.Add("B4");
        targetList.Add("T5");

        IList<object> toRemove = targetList.ToList().Where(k=>k.ToString().Contains("B")).ToList();

        OCRemoveMultiple(ref targetList, toRemove);

        targetList.ToList().ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine(k.ToString())); // Writes "T1", "T2" and "T5"
```