# Explain this LINQ code?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I asked a question in which one of the response contained the following LINQ code:

```
var selected = lstAvailableColors.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
selected.ForEach( x => { lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(x); });
selected.ForEach( x => { lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(x);});
```

Can someone explain the above LINQ to a total newbie?

Comment: I updated my original answer with an explanation

Comment: Link to the original question? Or post your explanation here as an answer?

Comment: Link to explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808006/collection-was-modified-enumaration-may-not-execute-error-when-removing-a-listit/808033#808033

Comment: @Xaisoft -- it would actually have been better to use a comment to ask for clarification in the same question rather than open a new question -- absent the original context -- about the code.

Comment: I thought about that, but was thinking Jared might have not looked the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LINQ operators use what's called a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), so you can read the first line as a series of function calls. Assuming that `lstAvailableColors` is `IEnumerable<T>`, the idea is that each available color flows through the LINQ operators.

Let's break it down:

```
var selected = lstAvailableColors
    // each item is cast to ListItem type
    .Cast<ListItem>() 
    // items that don't pass the test (Selected == true) are dropped
    .Where(i => i.Selected) 
    // turn the stream into a List<ListItem> object
    .ToList();
```

EDIT: As JaredPar pointed out, the last line above (`ToList()`) is very important.  If you didn't do this, then each of the two `selected.ForEach` calls would re-run the query. This is called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) and is an important part of LINQ.

You could rewrite this first line like this:

```
var selected = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (var item in lstAvailableColors)
{
    var listItem = (ListItem)item;

    if (!listItem.Selected)
         continue;

    selected.Add(listItem);
}
```

The last two lines are just another way to write a foreach loop and could be rewritten as:

```
foreach (var x in selected)
{
    lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(x);
}

foreach (var x in selected)
{
    lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(X);
}
```

Probably the hardest part of learning LINQ is learning the flow of data and the syntax of [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: flow of data is exactly what is confusing.

Comment: Nice explanation. So in the end of the first line, selected only contains items that are selected.  Also, if selected is List<ListItem>, can I use that instead of var?  What is the reason for using var?

Comment: The only reason for using "var" is because sometimes you'll have things that are easy to understand but a pain to type, something awful like IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, ListItem>>.  It does nothing but save keystrokes.

Comment: 'var' is shorthand for asking the compiler to infer the variable type based on what the variable is assigned to. Yes, you can indeed replace it with List<ListItem>. It's really a matter of preference. Most people would use 'var' here because it's easy to see that it's a List<ListItem> because of the .Cast<ListItem> call and the .ToList() call.

Comment: Could I have used object or is that different from var?

Comment: object would lose type safety.  var is just a C# shorthand telling the compiler "figure it out for yourself" (the compiled code would look as if you typed out the List<ListItem>) object would be explicitly telling the compiler to treat the result as "object" and you wouldn't be able to call any methods on it other than the ones defined in object (ToString etc.) without casting back to List<ListItem>

Answer (score 3):

Explanation from original question.

The LINQ version works in two parts. The first part is the first line which finds the currently selected items and stores the value in a List. It's very important that the line contain the .ToList() call because that forces the query to execute immediately vs. being delayed executed.

The next two lines iterate through each value which is selected and remove or add it to the appropriate list. Because the selected list is already stored we are no longer enumerating the collection when we modify it.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd lines are pretty clear, but can you further explain the CAST in line 1.  I guess I am trying to understand what order the linq query is executing?

Comment: Basically: first, the code is casting all the elements in lstAvailableColors to type ListItem. Then, a filter is applied to generate a subset that represents all ListItems where Selected == true. Finally, the IEnumerable<ListItem> returned by the filter is converted into a List<ListItem>. -- Because of the enumerable semantics it's not *exactly* like this - but that's the general order you're looking for.

Comment: More accurately:  It takes each element in the lstAvailableColors collection in turn.  When it gets to each element, it casts it to a ListItem.  Then, if the item's IsSelected is true, it adds it to a new list that it's created.  Because of the way IEnumerable and iterators work, it works on one item at a time.

Comment: @mquander - true, but I didn't want to confuse matters by getting that explicit. =) +1 nonetheless for accuracy.

Comment: (not that +1 on a comment means a whole heck of a lot other than kudos =P)

Answer (score 2):

It casts each item in the list to type ListItem, then selects only those whose Selected property is true.  It then creates a new list containing just these items.  For each item in the resulting list, it adds that item to the selected colors list and removes it from the available colors list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some translations would help

```
var selected = lstAvailableColors.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
```

could be written as:

```
List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (ListItem item in lstAvailableColors)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        selected.Add(item);
}
```

Note that `foreach` implicitly casts the items on the list to whatever type the loop variable is, in this case `ListItem`, so that takes care of the `Cast<ListItem>` on the list. `Where` filters out any items for which the expression is `false`, so I do the same thing with an `if` statement. Finally, `ToList` turns the sequence into a list, so I just build up a list as I go. The end result is the same.

And:

```
selected.ForEach( x => { lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(x); });
selected.ForEach( x => { lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(x); });
```

could be written as:

```
foreach (ListItem item in selected)
{
    lstSelectedColors.Items.Add(item);
    lstAvailableColors.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

I doubt if there's a good reason for writing it the more obscure way in that case.