# Selecting Multiple Items From ListBox causes Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a simple code in which i am Transferring Items of one listBox to one Another on btnAdd_Click Event and     btnRemove_Click Event resp.
This was working Fine when The **selectionMode="Single"** and at that point of time i had no need to use foreach inbtn_Add_Click. But Now i've changed **selectionMode="Multiple"** and used **foreach** in btnAdd_Click and when i am selecting multiple items from ListBox it is creating the following Error:-

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**

```
 class Movies
{
    private Int32 _Id;
    private string _movieName;
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }
    public string movieName
    {
        get { return _movieName; }
        set { _movieName = value; }
    }

    public Movies(Int32 ID, string MovieName)
    {
        Id = ID;
        movieName = MovieName;
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Movies> list = new List<Movies>();
        list.Add(new Movies(1, "Movie1"));
        list.Add(new Movies(2, "Movie2"));
        list.Add(new Movies(3, "Movie3"));
        list.Add(new Movies(4, "Movie4"));
        list.Add(new Movies(5, "Movie5"));
        list.Add(new Movies(6, "Movie6"));
        list.Add(new Movies(7, "Movie7"));
        lstMain.DataSource = list;
        lstMain.DataBind();
    }     
}
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListItem list in lstMain.Items)// Here the error comes
    {   
        if(list.Selected)
        {
            lstFAvourite.ClearSelection();
            lstFAvourite.Items.Add(list);
            lstMain.Items.Remove(list);
        }
    }
}
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem list = lstFAvourite.SelectedItem;
    lstMain.ClearSelection();
    lstMain.Items.Add(list);
    lstFAvourite.Items.Remove(list);
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in lstFAvourite.Items)
    {
        lbl1.Text += "<li>" + item.Text;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is going wrong with the foreach loop in btnAdd_Click Event....

Thanks..

Comment: See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808006/collection-was-modified-enumeration-may-not-execute-error-when-removing-a-listi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove items from an enumeration while you are looping through it using a `foreach`, which is what the error message is trying to tell you.

Switching to a straight `for` loop will get your code to execute:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(var i=0; i<lstMain.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var list = lstMain.Items[i];
        lstFAvourite.ClearSelection();
        lstFAvourite.Items.Add(list);
        lstMain.Items.Remove(list);
        i--;
    }
}
```

However, I believe this code will add all items from `lstMain` to `lstFAvourite`. I think perhaps that we should be looking at the `Selected` property of the `ListItem` as well in the `for` loop. For example:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < lstMain.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var list = lstMain.Items[i];
        if(!list.Selected) continue;
        lstFAvourite.ClearSelection();
        lstFAvourite.Items.Add(list);
        lstMain.Items.Remove(list);

        //Decrement counter since we just removed an item            
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanq... But Can you please elaborate: Why foreach is unable to accomplish this. ?

Comment: Because you're not allowed to modify an enumeration while you are using the enumeration in a foreach. Removing the item from lstMain in the foreach modifies the enumeration, which causes the error.

Comment: Ok Ok .. I get this now. Thanque So much .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

```
lstMain.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach( item =>
        {
            if(item.Selected)
            {
                lstFAvourite.Items.Add(item);
                lstMain.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    );
lstFAvourite.ClearSelection();
```

N.B: much slower than the for loop method.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove list box items using a for loop using an increment (++) statement, eventually that loop will throw out of bounds error failing to finish removing all the items you want. Use decrement (--) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` is because, while you are deleting the items from the list its affecting the sequence. You need to iterate the items in `reverse` order for this.

```
for (int i = lstMain.Items.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
    ListItem list = lstMain.Items[i];
    lstFAvourite.ClearSelection();
    lstFAvourite.Items.Add(list);
    lstMain.Items.Remove(list);
}
```

Comment: It does not contain definition of Reverse. am i missing some assembly refrence??

Comment: @AnilKumar `Reverse` is not supporting with `ListItemCollection`. You can use `for loop`. Check my edit.

Comment: Hmmm Ok. By the way would you tell me why do we use `reverse`, or in which circumstances?

Comment: @AnilKumar. Assume that you have 3 items. While iterating items normally(in ascending) it will go from 1, 2 and 3. Suppose, if you remove 2nd item, the 3rd one will become in the place of 2. So in the next iteration, if we look for the 3rd one, it wont be there right? If you do it in the reverse order, even though we delete 2nd item from the list, in the next iteration we will look for 1st item only, not the 3rd. So, there won't be any issues. So, whenever you delete items from a list/array do it in reverse order.

Comment: Ok ok Thanx For this. shanish