# An error occurred on Update SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql

When i try to remove some Data from my Database i have the error:
An error occurred on Update

```
using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
{
    var order = context.Pages.Where(o => o.Name == pName);
    foreach (var u in order)
    {
        context.Pages.Remove(u);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks for help !

**Bug fixed:
It was because I don't remove data from other table that is link with my table**

Comment: What is the _complete_ error message exactly?

Comment: An error occurred while updating the entries. For more information, see the inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808006/collection-was-modified-enumeration-may-not-execute-error-when-removing-a-listi), you can't modify the collection during enumeration.

It works if you materialize the query in a collection:

```
var orderListToDelete = context.Pages.Where(o => o.Name == pName).ToList();
foreach (var u in orderListToDelete)
{
    context.Pages.Remove(u);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: No, same error

Can be because no Data is Update and i try to SaveChanges ?

Comment: So the full error message is: _"An error occurred on Update"_? Set a breakpoint and look at the inner exception.

Comment: It's because i have link in my table and i don't have remove what is link before I think

Comment: @Cyril: Any chance that you post the full exception message? You get it by setting a breakpoint at the line `context.Pages.Remove(u);` and executing the statement in the debugger's quick watch window. Or you add a `Try-Catch` and set a breakoint in the `Catch`.

Comment: Yes it was because i don't remove data that is link before remove my Page

Answer (score 0):

I face this type of problem.But my solution is here.

```
var order = context.Pages.AsQueryable().Where(o => o.Name == pName);
if(order!=null)
 {
   order.ToList().ForEach(o=>context.Pages.Remove(o));
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

please try this.