# How can I remove an item from a listbox without using "Contains"?

Tags: c#, listbox, contains, indexof, listboxitems

I've got this code:

```
for (int i = listboxWork.Items.Count-1; i > -1; i--) 
{
    if (listboxWork.Items[i].Contains(tblSent))
    {
        listboxWork.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

...which I derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096489/c-sharp-removing-items-from-listbox), but my creaky old version of .NET (or maybe it's my puny version of .NET (Compact Framework) that's the problem) doesn't contain "Contains".

I reckon I could replace that line with:

```
if (listboxWork.Items[i].ToString().IndexOf(tblSent) > -1)
```

...but am not overly confident that's the best way to do it. Is there a more acceptable way?

Comment: array might not have a contains operator, but are you sure that a list object doesnt?  You could reverse the list and do a foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Items` is a collection of objects, so you need to convert the element you are working with to a string before you can use `Contains`:

```
if (listboxWork.Items[i].ToString().Contains(tblSent))
```

Edit: since this is CompactFramework (which I failed to recognize in the post originally, the proper solution is to use String.IndexOf, which was already identified.

This is a perfectly acceptable mechanism, but if the CF supports it, I would strongly suggest using a case-insensitive comparison, especially if there is any user input involved in the evaluation:

```
if (x.Items[0].ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(tblSent.ToLower()) != -1)
```

Comment: That is sensible, but even doing it that way (the right way) is impossible in this Contains-challenged version of .NET I'm stuck with.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: I overlooked the CF issue earlier; you might want to adjust the tags in your question to include this. I have updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. I forgot how limiting CF was. Final approach (if the comparison does involve user input) is to convert everything to lowercase (or upper) prior to performing the comparison. I have updated the answer with this approach.

Comment: Yes; CF stands for Cheesy and Frustrating.