# Removing an Item from listbox via FindByText Method

Tags: c#, listbox

When a user clicks a checkbox it adds the item to the listbox, and when the user unchecks it, it must be removed from the list. I'm trying to use the FindByText method but it doesn't seem to appear in my visual studio. Here's my current work:

```
 if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
 {
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);
 }
 else
 {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items.FindByText(checkBox1.Text));
 }
```

Comment: I haven't used winforms in a long time, but judging by your code you're adding a string, and then trying to remove a control. Are you sure it shouldn't simply be: `listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

You add `String` so you should remove `String` as well; so you have no need in any `FindByText`:

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Text);
```

Complete fragment:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked) // "== true" is redundant
  listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);
else
  listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Text);
```

or even

```
  // To prevent double adding
  listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Text);

  if (checkBox1.Checked)
    listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

to find an item by text in listbox you would have to iterate through all the items 
refer to this article about removing items from listbox : [C# removing items from listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096489/c-sharp-removing-items-from-listbox)