# How do you delete a listview item by name or Index?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `textBox` where you can enter a name then you can click on a `Button` to delete that item with that name in a `listview`.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (ListViewItem Searchstr in listView1.Name)
   {
      listView1.Items.Remove(Searchstr);
   }
}
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# removing items from listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096489/c-sharp-removing-items-from-listbox)

Comment: A simple google search of your Title yields many results.. please show more effort on your part next time .. respectfully speaking ..

Comment: There should be no `ListViewItem`s in `listView1.Name`. I mean it. Not even a single one.

Answer (score 0):

```
void deleteItemFromListBox(string stringToDelete, ListView listBoxToDeleteItem)
{
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxToDeleteItem.Items.Count; i++)
{
if(stringToDelete==listBoxToDeleteItem.Items[i].Text)
{
  listBoxToDeleteItem.Items[i].Remove();
}
}
}
```

Function takes string and listview than deletes listview element that contains the string.