# Get current element in For Each

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get the current element that `For Each` is executing but I'm getting

> InvalidOperationException: The list with which the enumerator is associated has been modified. The enumerator can only be used if the list remains constant.

That's the code:

```
For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
    Try
        [..code]
    Catch ex As WebException
        If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
            Dim Risposta As DialogResult
            Risposta = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Errore: Impossibile trovare l'SWF {0}. Continuare?", i), "Errore durante il check degli SWF!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If Risposta = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(i) <- Thats where the error pops up
            End If
            If Risposta = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Errore: {0}", ex.Message), "Errore sconosciuto durante il check degli SWF!")
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Try
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# removing items from listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096489/c-sharp-removing-items-from-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to store the items to be removed and then remove them after going through the ListBox items, like this:

```
Sub RemoveImpossible(itemsToRemove As List(Of String))
    For Each s In itemsToRemove
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(s)
    Next

End Sub

Sub X()
    Dim impossibleItems As New List(Of String)

    For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
        Try
            ' [..code]
        Catch ex As WebException
            If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
                Dim Risposta As DialogResult
                Risposta = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Errore: Impossibile trovare l'SWF {0}. Continuare?", i), "Errore durante il check degli SWF!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If Risposta = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                    impossibleItems.Add(i)
                End If
                If Risposta = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                    Application.Exit()
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Errore: {0}", ex.Message), "Errore sconosciuto durante il check degli SWF!")
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        End Try
    Next

    RemoveImpossible(impossibleItems)

End Sub
```

That way, some other processing on the items which did not work could be done afterwards, if that was a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cant modify an iterator, therefore you have to use a regular for loop.

```
For i as Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count() - 1 To 0 Step -1
    ListBox1.Items(i)          //to access
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i) //to remove
Next
```

added code fixes from comments

Comment: It's usual to iterate from the end to the start (`For i = ListBox1.Items.Count() - 1 To 0 Step -1`) so that removing an item doesn't change the indexes of the remaining items to be iterated over.