# How to use a selected item from a listbox as the name of a list

Tags: c#

my listbox1 is populated with the names of the lists i have created which when a name is selected populate listbox2 with a list objects from that list that is already created. Then when an item from listbox2 is selected it populates textboxes with the different elements of that object.

I have a delete button and when clicked i want to delete the current object from the list named in listbox1. How do i do that? This is what i've tried.

this does not work. it gives me an error:

> CS1061.  'char' does not contain a definition for 'requestDesc' and no extension method 'requestDesc' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have everything else working but this.

```
string selecItem = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
var find2 = selecItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.requestDesc == curItem);
if (find2 != null)
{
    selecItem.Remove(find2);
}
```

Comment: `selecItem` is a `string`. Since string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, `x` in `FirstOrDefault` is `char`. Since it's not clear what `curItem` is, it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you want `var selecItem = listBox2.SelectedItems`?

Comment: The error you get is pretty clear
Your ```selectItem``` is type of ```string``` when you call ```FirstOfDefault``` on string you iterating through individual characters of the string, at lambda expression ```x => x.requestDesc == curItem``` compiler could not find ```requestDesc``` property on ```char```

Comment: string curItem = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem); to use to search through the list of objects and populate the textboxes

Comment: `string curItem = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);` returns the _text representation_ of the item. [Docs for GetItemText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `x.SelectedValue` and it should compile:

```
string selecItem = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
var find2 = selecItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SelectedValue == curItem); 
if (find2 != null) { selecItem.Remove(find2); }
```

However it won't work because the find2 is a Ref type and it won't be equal to the item in listbox2.

You might choose to iterate over the items instead, or even better thanks to Jimi in the comments:

```
string selecItem = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem); 
int itemIdx = listBox1.FindStringExact(selecItem); 
if (itemIdx != ListBox.NoMatches) { selecItem.Items.RemoveAt(itemIdx); }
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstringexact?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Jimi is right, this was written on the top of my head.

Comment: Except, the last line should be `if (itemIdx != ListBox.NoMatches) { listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(itemIdx); }`: `selecItem` is the same old string guy :)

Answer (score 0):

`selecItem` is a `string`. Like "12345abc".

A `string` does not contain a `requestDesc`. It just contain `chars`.

What you need to do is to remove it from the listbox by useing something like `listBox1.Items.Remove`

You can find more on it here [C# removing items from listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096489/c-sharp-removing-items-from-listbox#2096633)

Comment: It should do that, through `Remove`, if you are able ro select the correct item.