# Cannot remove items from ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

When trying to run this method I get an error:

List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.

```
foreach (var item in lstPhotos.SelectedItems)
{
    lstPhotos.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

How can I remove the selected items?

Comment: you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380451/how-do-i-do-i-loop-through-items-in-a-list-box-and-then-remove-that-item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(lstPhotos.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
{
    lstPhotos.Items.Remove(lstPhotos.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the foreach loop doesn't allow you to modify the collection being enumerated. if you need to modify the collection use a for loop instead.

edit:

I am leaving my original answer above, but upon coding this it became apparent that a while loop is better suited to this problem because of the dynamic length of the SelectedItems property.

```
while(lstPhotos.SelectedItems.Length > 0)
{
    lstPhotos.Items.Remove(lstPhotos.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

Comment: How can I access each individual item then?

Comment: A `while` loop might be appropriate as well. Is there a property such as `SelectedItem`? You know, it all depends on the specific collection /library that you are using.

Comment: thanks, i changed my answer to be more useful on your suggestion