# Delete from list using foreach using listbox selected item

Tags: c#

I am trying to use this method that is ran from a button click that will retrieve the select item from a listbox then remove this item from the list. Whenever i run the code i get this error:
"List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.".

I'm completely stumped.

```
    public void DeleteSale()
    {
        foreach (BootSale b in lstBootSales.SelectedItems)
        {

            lstBootSales.Items.Remove(b.Id);
            lstBootSales.Items.Remove(b.Date);

            DisplayAllBootSales();
        }
    }
```

`DisplayAllBootSales();`simply refreshes the listbox values afterwards

I have a List "BootSale" where I store information which is written to a listbox. I want to be able to click the item in the listbox then click delete and it will be completely removed from the system

Comment: You can't modify a collection while enumerating through it.

Comment: What does DisplayAllBootSales do?

Comment: @bash.d Display all boot sales?

Comment: @DGibbs Thanks, Captain Obvious!

Comment: Ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but you can create another temporary list, insert everything you want to remove to it, then after you're loop ends, remove all the items in the temporary list from the original list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot remove items from ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445678/cannot-remove-items-from-listbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this:

```
class Foo {

    BootSaleList bootsalelist;

    public void DeleteSale()
    {
        foreach (BootSale b in lstBootSales.SelectedItems.OfType<BootSale>().ToArray())
        {
            //temp.Remove(b); -- no more of this guy
            bootsalelist.ReturnList().Remove(b);
            lstBootSales.Items.Remove(b);

            // and no more of these guys:

            //lstBootSales.Items.Remove(b.Id); 
            //lstBootSales.Items.Remove(b.Date);
            //DisplayAllBootSales();
        }
    }

 }
```

where:

```
[Serializable]
public class BootSaleList : IDisplay
{
    private List<BootSale> bootsales;

    public List<BootSale> ReturnList()
    {
        return bootsales;
    }
}
```

and it will work perfectly

Comment: thanks for help tried this but get the error "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to 'Bootsale_project.BootSale'"

Comment: Code now runs fine but it simply deletes the content of the listbox and not the actual list

Comment: And that is **precisely** what yours would've done if it would not have crashed with the exception...

Comment: I apologise I maybe wasnt clear at first I have a List "BootSale" where I store information which is written to a listbox. I want to be able to click the item in the listbox then click delete and it will be completely removed from the system.

Comment: I have to ask how it is possible that `SelectedItems` which is a subset of `Items` contain things whose properties (`Id` and `Date`) are contained in `Items` (for which it would be a good idea to delete them from `Items`). I really thought you were asking about the error "List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change." and that your code was just a sample... Is that error gone or not ? Are you asking how to actually **do it** ? Look at my latest edit. Personally I really don't understand the removing of `.Id` and `.Date`...

Comment: We should take this to chat but you don't have enough rep to do that. Check the latest edit...

Comment: anywhere that bootsalelist.ReturnList() is written on formbasedui i get this error "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Assignment_2.BootSaleList.ReturnList()' and 'Assignment_2.BootSaleList.ReturnList()'"

Comment: Look in the "Assignment_2" projects references folder. Make sure "Assigment_2" doesn't reference itself. If you find "Assignment_2" in the reference list of the "Assignment_2" project, **delete it** ! Please note that this is the last comment I'm writing because it's not nice to transform the comment section in a chat window. If you need further assistance place another question. If you feel the original question has been solved mark the answer you felt helped you the most to overcome **what you asked**...

Comment: I LOVE YOU, Thanks for all the help it actually working now i would give rep if it would let me

Comment: Don't worry bout the rep and "thanks for the flowers" :). It's good that it's working. StackOverflow will forgive us for these last chat messages. If you wish to tell us what you changed that made it work so that other people seeing this question can get an idea of how to solve such a situation... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all. You can't remove items from a list you are iterating over. You must remove the items outside of the `foreach` loop. One simple fix is to use a regular `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is looping the list Top - Down (instead of down - top)

```
for(int i = YourListItems.Count(); i > 0; i--)
{
    // Remove from list
}
```

This way will prevent any index errors.

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a collection from within a foreach, you could however use a temporary list, something along the lines of:

```
public void DeleteSale()
{
    List<T> temp = lstBootSales;
    foreach (BootSale b in lstBootSales.SelectedItems)
    {
        temp.Items.Remove(b.Id);
        temp.Items.Remove(b.Date);

        DisplayAllBootSales();
    }

    lstBootSales = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking on your code I might assume, that `lstBootSales` holds a list of `BootSale`. But you are trying to delete something different than BootSale. Also use `for` instead of foreach:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lstBootSales.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            lstBootSales.Items.Remove(lstBootSales.SelectedItems[i]);

            DisplayAllBootSales();
        }
```