# How to delete multiple checked items from CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I know how to remove a single `checkedItem` from `checkedlistbox`. But now, I want to remove  all the checked items in one go.

I tried this:

```
foreach (var item in List_Frente.CheckedItems)
            {
                List_Frente.Items.Remove(item);
            }
```

But as you probably know, it gives me an error,saying that, `List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.` How may I remove all `checkeditems` with a single click ?

Comment: Don't use a `foreach`. Use a `for`.

Comment: Im not familiar with winforms, but can you do a `List_Frente.CheckedItems.ToList()`? if you can that will solve the problem

Comment: @HighCore not,  just `ToString()` =(

Comment: @HighCore `foreach` uses an iterator. You cannot make changes to a collection while there is an active iterator. You cannot do this, in its current form, with a `foreach`.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar but how would I get the value of the `checkeditems` without a `foreach` ?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < (List_Frente.Items.Count
; i++)` Check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e954th47.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do I loop through items in a list box and then remove that item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380451/how-do-i-do-i-loop-through-items-in-a-list-box-and-then-remove-that-item)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in List_Frente.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList())
{
    List_Frente.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

If you want to write it all in one line:

```
List_Frente.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList().ForEach(List_Frente.Items.Remove);
```

This only works if your items are of the same type, of course. Looks still crude, though.

Edit-Explanation:
`ToList()` creates a new list and thus, the original CheckedItems list can be changed, as the enumerator now enumerates our newly created list, not the original. The `OfType<string>()` is only there because we need something to call `ToList()` on.

Comment: OMG WORKED !! Thanks Jobo !

Comment: Your welcome, it would help all here if you would accept the answer then :)

Comment: I know, I was just making some tests, and I have to wait a few minuts before mark as the answer ;P ... Could you explain me why worked this way ? And not the way I did ?

Comment: @Ghaleon because the LinQ methods `OfType<T>` and `ToList()` create a new instance of a `List` and then you iterate on that. Instead of iterating the original collection, which will produce an exception if you removed an item from it while iterating.

Comment: @Jobo Nice one! You could add the LINQ-Variant to your answer: `List_Frente.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList().ForEach(List_Frente.Items.Remove);`

Answer (score 4):

```
while (checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count > 0) {
   checkedListBox.Items.RemoveAt(checkedListBox.CheckedIndices[0]);
}
```

Comment: +1 Can confirm this works. Kinda feel silly for not seeing it myself though, maybe that's why this didn't have any votes? Either way, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you modify the list you are iterating over. Use a for-statement to prevent this from happening:

```
for(var i=0; i<List_Frente.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    ((IList)List_Frente.CheckedItems).Remove(List_Frente.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```

As stated in [this MSDN-Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334839%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the `CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection` implements the `IList.Remove`-method explicitly, meaning you will have to cast the instances to `IList` to make this work.

Comment: Hi ! There's no such method as `ChedkItems.REMOVE()` . I tried but it doesnt exist ;\

Comment: Oh yeah, there's no ToList() as well ;s

Comment: Huh. I took a closer look a the regarding [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334839(v=vs.71).aspx) which clearly states that there is a `Remove`-Method - except that it needs to be implemented explicitly. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ghaleon I fixed the code. These classes introduced in the very early versions of .NET sometimes don't have all the comfort the new ones have ;)

Comment: @Spontifixus thanks you too man ! I'll save your code on my codes.txt hehe xD +1

Answer (score 2):

Might be an addon for this post.

To clear all the items.

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
object[] items = new object[checkedListBox.Items.Count];
checkedListBox.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
checkedListBox.Items.Clear();
checkedListBox.Items.AddRange(items);
```

I aim to return with an solution that are more beautiful and less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following solution:

```
    For i As Integer = checkedListBox.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If checkedListBox.GetItemChecked(i) Then
            checkedListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Be careful with that. You change the content of the list you are iterating over.