# multiple remove checkedlistbox items

Tags: c#, checkbox, checkboxlist

Hi on this site I found how to delete multiple checkedbox objects in a `checklistbox`
[How to delete multiple checked items from CheckedListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590726/how-to-delete-multiple-checked-items-from-checkedlistbox)

But it's not working for me.
My previous partner who handled this project before I did saved something in Global.answer class.  I have tried to modify that script like this:

```
for (int i = checkedListBoxAnswers.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (checkedListBoxAnswers.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked) 
    {
        Global.answers.RemoveAt(checkedListBoxAnswers.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

It can delete one checkbox correctly, but when I check for two or more checkboxes, it goes wrong...
I wonder how to do it correctly.

this is my delete button

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBoxAnswers.SelectedIndices.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Please select answer to be deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = checkedListBoxAnswers.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (checkedListBoxAnswers.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    Global.answers.RemoveAt(checkedListBoxAnswers.SelectedIndex);
                }
            }
            updateCheckListBoxAnswers();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What assurance do you have that the order of items in `Global.answers` matches that of the `CheckedListBox`?  And what effect does that have on the list box once you remove them?  I don't see that you're removing anything from the `CheckedListBox`.  And you're repeatedly removing using the `SelectedIndex`, which will not change throughout the loop.

Comment: @DonBoitnott it's simplely because i can delete any checkbox if i not include Global.answer....in my script which use Global.answer, it's can remove one checkbox correctly, if i checked two or more checkbox it's can delete same amount as checked but goes wrong delete...i guess u right, the problem in selectedIndex...if u have idea to fix it, it's will be helped

Comment: What are the items in `checkedListBoxAnswers` and `Global.answers`? Is there any unique key in them you can use to identify the correct item in `Global.answers` based on `checkedListBoxAnswers` instead of indices?

Comment: @DamirArh as i search with a few keyword...i don't find any related item between "checkedListBoxAnswer" and "Global.answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this...

```
Global.answers.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: it's work...i don't know if it's just simple like that

Answer (score 3):

in-fact here is correct code:

```
 CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection checkedItemColl = checkedListBoxAnswers.CheckedItems;

            for (int i = checkedItemColl.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int index = checkedItemColl[i - 1];
                checkedListBoxAnswers.Items.Remove(index);

            }
```

Comment: i don't know why but i still get same error...i try to convert it by this code "checkedItemColl = Convert.ToInt32(checkedItemColl);" first..but it's give more error

Comment: I have created, Tested and then sent you, you debug and see

Comment: can u explain how to chunk code? am i should create new or is there any way to chunk exact code from program?

Comment: O buddy the code you have for deletion, I am sure must be in Button_Click. just send me that, also tell me the argument type of the

Answer (score 2):

Because you using this code

```
Global.answers.RemoveAt(checkedListBoxAnswers.SelectedIndex);
```

this will delete only the selected first item in the list, you must pass the index of selected Checked Item ,So it will delete that item only,
This is how you get all checked Item from List:

```
CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection checkedItemColl = checkedListBoxAnswers.CheckedItems;

        for (int i = checkedItemColl.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = checkedItemColl[i - 1];
            checkedListBoxAnswers.Items.Remove(index);

        }
```

remove comments and test the code. hope you will get benifit from it.

Comment: i mean get wrong in "int x = checkedListBoxAnswers.Items[index];" can't can't implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'

Answer (score 1):

hie bro i have sample ... you can evolve tray this in your sweet home....

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    listBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]);
  if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    listBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are Removing an Object so Parse that Object into Integer
by this way

```
Convert.ToInt32(Object)
```

in your case it will be..

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
listBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]);
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
   listBox1.Items.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]));
}
```